# Writing to database in parallel in R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I try to write a table which is a processed subset of a global data variable, in a normal for loop this piece of code works fine but when I try to do it in parallel it raises an error.

Here is my piece of code;

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(odbc)
library(data.table)

nc <- detectCores() - 1

cs <- makeCluster(nc)

registerDoParallel(cs)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),driver = 'SQL Server',server = 'localserver',database = 'mydb', encoding = 'utf-8',timeout = 20)

range_to <- 1e6

set.seed(1)

random_df <- data.table(a = rnorm(n = range_to,mean = 2,sd = 1),
                        b = runif(n = range_to,min = 1,max = 300))


foreach(i=1:1000,.packages = c('odbc','data.table')) %dopar% {
  subk <- random_df[i,]
   
  subk <- subk**2

  odbc::dbWriteTable(conn = con,name = 'parallel_test',value = subk,row.names = FALSE,append = TRUE)
    
}
```

This code raises this error;

```
Error in {: task 1 failed - "unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbWriteTable' for signature '"Microsoft SQL Server", "character", "data.table"'"
```

Like I said before in a normal for loop it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `con` objects cannot be passed between processes. Try to recreate `con` for each process (_in_ its process, not in the parent process) before attempting to use it. In my case, I keep a list of connection arguments and do `con <- do.call(dbConnect, mycreds)` inside of each parallel process (though I'm using `future`/`promise`, not `foreach`, but the notion should still work).

Comment: @r2evans thanks, but this code was just for testing. normally I should connect to a remote server and do this work, I think I shouldn't send connection request several times in a very short time. could you suggest any alternative way ?

Comment: No. Connection objects cannot be passed between processes, there is nothing to say about that. I used to think that connecting multiple times would be a slowdown, and frankly the only empirical evidence I found to justify my concern about doing that was in very very high query loads, high-frequency and low-dataflow. Even then, instantiating the connection itself was _miniscule_ in the big scheme, and ultimately was not a factor for me. Regardless, you don't have a choice, binary objects like that cannot pass between processes.

Comment: @r2evans I found a similar problem that was asked before by chance, I think when I define the connection object for each cluster, there is no need to redefine it every time in the loop, I added the answer. I think it can be useful for you too. thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue by changing only creating connection object method by;

```
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cs, {library(odbc);con <- dbConnect(odbc(),driver = 'SQL Server',server = 'localserver',database = 'mydb', encoding = 'utf-8',timeout = 20)})
```